# EF - Conditionally allow saving a property value (which has a backing field)

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-2.2, abp

I have a `User` entity and an `EmailRecipient` entity with a -one-to-one relationship. Email recipients can also be created without a related User entity.

My `EmailRecipient` entity takes the `Name`, `Surname` and `EmailAddress` from the `User` entity if it is attached/included. I have set up the properties to return the backing-field value if it isn't null before it returns the User properties so I can specify an alternative name if I want.

When saving the `EmailRecipient`, EF looks at the `Name`, `Surname` and `EmailAddress` properties and populates the `EmailRecipient` table with the values from the `User` entity instead of using the backing field values. I would like these fields to remain NULL in the database providing I haven't set a value explicitly i.e. `recipient.Name = "new name";`

**My Question**: How can I make EF populate selected database fields based on the backing-field value instead of the property values? Or is there a completely different approach to solving this problem?

*EmailRecipient Entity:*

```cs
public class EmailRecipient
{
    private string _name;
    public virtual string Name 
    { 
        get { return User == null ? _name : _name ?? User.Name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    private string _surname;
    public virtual string Surname
    {
        get { return User == null ? _surname : _surname ?? User.Surname; }
        set { _surname = value; }
    }

    private string _emailAddress;
    public virtual string EmailAddress
    {
        get { return User == null ? _emailAddress : _emailAddress ?? User.EmailAddress; }
        set { _emailAddress = value; }
    }

    [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public User User { get; protected set; }
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some further digging, I think I have found the solution. Carefully reading Microsoft's [EF Core backing fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field) documentation, it seems that we can explicitly ask EF to read and write to the backing field instead of using the property.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EmailRecipient>().Property(x => x.Name)
        .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
}
```

The backing field remains `null` until a new `Name` is set i.e. `recipient.Name = "new name";` and because of this, I can use the `recipient.Name` property to return the `recipient._name` (as stored in the database) or if it is null, the `recipient.User.Name`